# InternJs, How to set base path on command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, intern

**Details:**

I have a directory structure like this.

```
 myapp
    root-one
       -web
         -app
         -tests
    root-two
       -grunt
          node_modules
             .bin
               intern-runner
               selenium-standalone
             intern
             selenium-standalone
             grunt-shell
          Gruntfile.js
```

From my grunt file I am using shell npm to launch the selenium standalone server like so..

```
shell: {
   intern : {
      options: { stdout: true},
         command: [
            "cd node_modules/.bin",
            "start selenium-standalone start",
            "intern-runner config=tests/intern basePath=../../../../root-one/web"
         ].join('&&')
      }
   }
}

grunt.registerTask('intern', ['shell:intern']);
```

After running my grunt command **grunt intern**, selenium starts but I get the following error from intern-runner.

```
Error: Failed to load module tests/intern 
from C:/myapp/root-two/grunt/node_modules/.bin/tests/intern.js
```

Now because I set the path (or so I thought) using `basePath=../../../../root-one/web`. I would have expected it to try to execute from `C:/myapp/root-one/web/tests/intern.js` instead of remaining in the `.bin` directory.

**Question:**

So really the question is. What is the proper way to set the basePath for intern-runner on the command line? Because this doesn't seem to work. And according to the [docs](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#test-runner)...

> You can also specify any valid [configuration option](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#common-config) as an argument on
>   the command-line.

Which leads me to believe I probably just have the syntax wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this doesn't quite work the way I was expecting it to. As discussed here: https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/449

So for now the work around was to just install intern globally vs trying to run it locally out of my project. So instead I did..

```
npm install intern -g
```

With my project structure like so...

```
 myapp
    root-one
       -web
         -app
         -tests
    root-two
       -grunt
          node_modules
             .bin
               selenium-standalone
             selenium-standalone
             grunt-shell
          Gruntfile.js
```

Basically just removed intern because it is installed globally now. Which is located at the following on windows..

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern
```

And my Gruntfile has been changed too the following. After starting selenium I change directory back to the appropriate location to run the `intern-runner` command.

```
shell: {
   intern : {
      options: { stdout: true},
         command: [
            "cd node_modules/.bin",
            "start selenium-standalone start",
            "cd ../../../../root-one/web",
            "intern-runner config=tests/intern
         ].join('&&')
      }
   }
}

grunt.registerTask('intern', ['shell:intern']);
```